# If Galois group is $D_8$ then show that an intermediate extension has quadratic subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Given that $F$ is degree extension $4$ of $\mathbb Q$ which is not Galois. If $K$ is Galois closure of $F$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ is $D_8$ then I have to show that $F$ has subfield that is quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q$. The exact statement of the problem is `if and only if` but backward part is easier. I don't see show fundamental theorem of Galois theory helps since there is no subgroup of Galois group that fixes $F$. For quartic, the galois group are computed by resolvent cubic. Should I look in that direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[K:F] = 2$ and $F:\mathbb Q$ is not Galois, so via the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, $F$ corresponds to an order $2$ subgroup $\Gamma(F)$ of $D_8$ that is not a normal subgroup. (This $\Gamma(F)$ is the subgroup of the Galois group $Gal(K:\mathbb Q)$ that fixes $F$.)

To show that $F$ contains a $E$ such that $[E:\mathbb Q] = 2$, think what $E$ would correspond to via the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. We have $[K:E] = 4$ and $F \supset E \supset \mathbb Q$, so $E$ would correspond to an order $4$ subgroup $\Gamma(E)$ of $D_8$, with $\Gamma(F) \subset \Gamma (E) \subset D_8$.

Thus, using the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, we've transformed your problem into a group theory problem:

> Prove that every non-normal order $2$ subgroup of $D_8$ is contained in an order $4$ subgroup of $D_8$.

Comment: I was not reading FTGT properly :(